# How can i update checkbox checked rows when i click on save amt button in php

Tags: php

I want to update checkbox checked rows when i click on save amt button. Please help me i getting error.

```
<?php
include_once("config.php");
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
  $paitAmt = $_POST['paidamt'];
  $uid = $_POST['uid'];
  $array = array($paitAmt, $uid);
  foreach ($array as list($paitAmt, $uid)) {
  $sql = "UPDATE tbldemo SET paidAmt = '$paitAmt' WHERE id = '$uid'";
  echo $sql;
  $result = mysql_query($sql);
  echo 'Updated Successfully';
  }
}
?>
```

[image]

Comment: I need your html code as well? Are check boxes in array? Are they having some ids with them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?php
include_once("config.php");
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
  $paitAmt = $_POST['paidamt'];
  $uid = $_POST['uid'];
  foreach ($paitAmt as $key=>$value) {
  $sql = "UPDATE tbldemo SET paidAmt = '$value' WHERE id = '{$uid[$key]}'";
  //echo $sql;
  $result = mysql_query($sql);
  echo 'Updated Successfully';
  }
}
?>
```